# ¿Cómo puedo llamar el resultado de una función que se encuentra en una clase, para así poder crear otra función con el resultado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, clase

Actualmente me encuentro aprendiendo Python porque quiero realizar trading de manera autónoma, me encuentro actualmente con un inconveniente que no puedo solucionar. Quiero comparar el resultado de la función `historicalDataEnd(self, reqId, start, end):` que está dentro de la clase `MovingAverages` con X función que yo desee crear que arroje X valor y poder compararlas para ejecutar otra secuencia condicional.

Con `client.reqHistoricalData(0, contract, currentTime, '2 D', '5 mins', 'MIDPOINT', 0, 2, False, [])`que está dentro de la función `main():` solicita los datos al broker y el broker envia la informacion de vuelta a la función `@iswrapper historicalDataEnd(self, reqId, start, end):` y me arroja la información, pero no he podido utilizar esta información solicitada para compararla con la información de otra función similar.

¿Cómo podría realizar esto? Muchas gracias de ante mano:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

from ibapi.client import EClient, Contract
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.utils import iswrapper

class MovingAverage(EWrapper, EClient):
    ''' Serves as the client and the wrapper '''

    def __init__(self, addr, port, client_id):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

        # Initialize members
        self.stock_vals = collections.deque(maxlen=13) #This number define SMA #
        self.avg_vals = []

        # Connect to TWS
        self.connect(addr, port, client_id)

        # Launch the client thread
        thread = Thread(target=self.run)
        thread.start()

    @iswrapper
    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        # Append the closing price to the deque
        self.stock_vals.append(bar.close)

        # Compute the average if 100 values are available
        if len(self.stock_vals) == 13:
            avg = sum(self.stock_vals) / len(self.stock_vals)
            self.avg_vals.append(avg)

    @iswrapper
    def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId, start, end):
        sma13 = (float(self.avg_vals[-1])) #This one print the last SMA requested
        print (sma13) --------- > #Quiero comparar este resultado con el de otra funcion fuera de la clase 




    def error(self, reqId, code, msg):
        print('Error {}: {}'.format(code, msg))


def main():
    # Create the client and connect to TWS
    client = MovingAverage('127.0.0.1', 7497, 0)

    # Define a contract for IBM stock
    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = "MNQ"
    contract.secType = "FUT"
    contract.exchange = "GLOBEX"
    contract.currency = "USD"
    contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = 202006

    # Request six months of historical data
    currentTime = datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
    client.reqHistoricalData(0, contract, currentTime, '2 D', '5 mins', 'MIDPOINT', 0, 2, False, [])

    # Sleep while the request is processed
    time.sleep(1)

    # Disconnect from TWS
    client.disconnect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Y porque no llamas la función dentro de `historicalDataEnd`?

Comment: @loki Me podrías explicar por fa cómo lo harías?  es que `historialDataEnd` responde al llamado de `client.reqHistoricalData(0, contract, currentTime, '2 D', '5 mins', 'MIDPOINT', 0, 2, False, [])`.